# Factory methods with Go generics

Tags: go, generics

This is my first time with Go generics and I wanted some help in understanding how a factory method can be implemented using Go generics

Consider that I have this type hierarchy

```
type Base[T comparable] interface {
    // Value returns the value of the identifier
    Value() T
}
```

I implement the above interface concretely:

```
type ConcreteImpl struct {
    value int64
}

func (i *ConcreteImpl) Value() int64 {
    return i.value
}
```

Now I want to define a factory method of the following form

```
func Build[T comparable](value any) Base[T] {
    if (!someCondition()) {
        return ConcreteImpl{value: value.(int64)}

    }
    return nil
}
```

My problem is that the compiler complains on the `Build` method with the following error

```
ConcreteImpl does not implement Base[T]. 
Have Value() int64
Want Value() T
```

Can someone explain this error and a resolution?

**Version of Go being used : 1.19**

Comment: There's no covariance in Go. Even though `int64` satisfies the `comparable` contraint, `Base[int64]` (which `ConcreteImpl` satisfies) is no subtype of `Base[T]` (where `T` is subject to the `comparable` constraint).

Answer (score -2):

Tldr: [This should work](https://go.dev/play/p/WO0mumPvDhN):

```
func Build[T comparable](value any) Base[T] {
    if someCondition() {
        return any(&ConcreteImpl{value: value.(int64)}).(Base[T])

    }
    return nil
}
```

The reason is that every code path, even the dead ones, must compile. To achieve this, the return value must be a `Base[T]` in every code path. A `ConcreteImpl` is only a `Base[T]` when `T = int64`, so it cannot be implicitly or explicitly casted to a `Base[T]` in the general case. As a result, a type assertion is needed.

This has nothing to do with covariance but about the totality of the conversion. A `Base[int64]` cannot be converted to a `Base[T]` with every `T` satisfying `comparable`. It will always fail with for example `T = int8`, and even with covariance this will fail.